# EC2 instance is showing unhealthy after reboot

Tags: amazon-elb

I have setup one Application load balancer crossed zoned. Initially all instances are in healthy status but after reboot a instance that particular instance shows unhealthy in the target group.

Protocol HTTP
Path /
Port traffic port
Healthy threshold 5
Unhealthy threshold 5
Timeout 5
Interval 30
Success codes 200

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your webservice has successfully started back up after you rebooted it?

You'll likely need to provide much more information (such as OS + webservice) if you are to get any proper answer, but as a general suggestion you your remote into your EC2 instance and figure out if the service (IIS, Apache, Nginx or otherwise) is actually running.

Comment: Hello Steven, Yes everything is working fine. I'm able access web application when trying without ALB.